# How to sum varchar fields from table between start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to sum fields which is declared as `varchar(50)` from the table, *Emp_Data* between start date and end date and group it by *Emp_ID*.

**Emp_Data** schema

```
Emp_ID as varchar(50),
Emp_Name as varchar(50),
Processing_Date as datetime,
PR as varchar(50),
Lines as varchar(50),
Followup as varchar(50)
```

**Employee_Details** schema

```
emp_id as varchar(50),
Emp_Name as varchar(50),
Manager as varchar(50),
Target as int.
```

I tried a query:

```
SELECT PS.emp_id,
       PS.emp_Name,
       Sum(PR_Validation),
       Sum(Lines),
       Sum(RC_Number),
       Sum(Followup),
       Sum(Manual_Order),
       Sum(Quotes_Processed)
FROM   Emp_Data AS PS
INNER JOIN tbl_Employee_Details AS ED
  ON ED.manager = 'Viswanathan' 
  AND PS.processing_date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017'
GROUP  BY PS.emp_Id
```

but I am getting an error

> "Column 'Emp_Data.Emp_Name' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

I am new to SQL Server.

Comment: Why are trying to *sum fields which is declared as varchar(50)*. It makes no sense

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  You might also want to explain why the data structure is so poorly designed.

Comment: You're also not joining the tables together at all, so your query doesn't make much sense. You probably should ask someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using SQL Server.  If so, the best approach is to store your numbers AS NUMBERS.  That is why SQL has more than one built-in data types.  They are used for different things.

But, if you stuck with strings, then sue `try_convert()`.  I don't know the actual types, so I'll just throw in integers:

```
SELECT PS.emp_id, PS.emp_Name,
       Sum(try_convert(int, PR_Validation)),
       Sum(try_convert(int, Lines)),
       Sumtry_convert(int, (RC_Number)),
       Sum(try_convert(int, Followup)),
       Sum(try_convert(int, Manual_Order)),
       Sum(try_convert(int, Quotes_Processed))
FROM Emp_Data PS INNER JOIN
     tbl_Employee_Details AS ED
     ON ED.manager = 'Viswanathan' AND
        PS.processing_date >= '2017-01-01' AND
        PS.processing_date < '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY PS.emp_Id, PS.emp_Name ;
```

For a discussion on why I changed the `BETWEEN` to inequalities, read Aaron Bertrand's [blog on the subject](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  (Note that this applies to databases other than SQL Server.)  I also think that you should always use ISO standard date formats, either YYYYMMDD (which is the best to use in SQL Server) or YYYY-MM-DD (which is almost as good, works in other databases, and is more human-readable).

It is also possible that you intend `COUNT()` rather than `SUM()`.  In that case, the conversion is not necessary.